# FAQPage schema in PHP not formatted correctly

Tags: json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, schema.org

I'm trying to build a schema for a page that has FAQ questions. The code works but something is wrong with the formatting. The problem is that the array "mainEntity" is on every question.

Here is my code

```
    $posts = get_field('section_faq_relation');
    if( $posts ): 
        
        $schema_faq_questions = array();
        
        foreach( $posts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post);
            $headline = get_the_title();
            $articlebody = get_the_content();
            $schema_faq_question = array(
                '@type'     => 'Question',
                'name'     => $headline,
                'acceptedAnswer' => array(
                    '@type'     => 'Answer',
                    'text'     => wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $articlebody )
                 )
            );
        
         array_push($schema_faq_questions, $schema_faq_question);
         endforeach;
        
         $schema_faq_all = array(
             '@context'  => 'http://schema.org',
             '@type'     => 'FAQPage',
             'mainEntity' => $schema_faq_questions
         );
    
        echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema_faq_all) . '</script>';
    endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

My code looks OK and returns this if I look at the json it's outputting. mainEntity is an array that holds all the questions.

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [

      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "dolor sit amet",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "quasi architecto",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "re veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
        }
      }
    ]

}
```

But if I run the schema.org validator it returns:

[image: schema output FAQPage]

Every question has "mainEntity". I don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: How else would you expect the validator to format it?

Comment: with mainEntitity showing once with all the questions and answers.

Comment: Did you manage to find an example where the validator formats it that way? It might be that this is just the way the validator formats arrays with multiple values.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your output.

Comment: The output of the debugger not related to stackoverflow. The markup is valid: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/faqpage